# Force Extend a method which has a body

Tags: php, class, methods

Which one is the best way to extend a method in a class which has a body?

```
class one
{
     public function methOne($var)
     {
         // Something here
     }

     public function methTwo($var)
     {
         // Something here
     }
}


class two extends one
{
    public function methTwo($var, $varTwo)
    {
        if($varTwo === true)
            parent::methTwo($var);
        else
             return 100;

    }
}
```

In the example above, is there a way I can force class two to extend methTwo considering the parent methTwo has a logic I'll reuse in some condition?
I was thinking to abstract the class and the method, but I cannot abstract a method which is not empty.

Comment: You will at least have to have the same number of parameters otherwise it won't work at all.

Comment: You could always have $varTwo = null which would work. Same constructor signature.

Comment: Ok, but in the example I'm not forcing the method to be extended. I'm looking for a way to force the method as in this way who is using the class can easily avoid extending that method

Comment: I don't understand the question. You ask which one is the best way to do something, but then only show one way. What is the other way that we're supposed to compare with?

Comment: Are you asking what you can put in class `one` to indicate that `methOne()` requires that subclasses override it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the method `protected` in the base class. If a subclass doesn't override it, callers will get an error because they can't access the name. But subclasses can call it from their overriding method, because protected names are accessible to subclasses.

Comment: Fantastic! I didn't thought about method visibility ;)